# Opening external links in Google+

Tags: google-plus

Why can't i open external links from within Google+?
Tried with Firefox and Chrome (even without addons and with new clean profiles)

When I click a link, it opens in a new tab and tries to load, but eventually stops with a (translated from Norwegian):

```
Connection aborted
```

If I paste the url in adress-field the page loads fine.

Running Ubuntu 13.04.

Tried booting from a live 13.04 and used google apps-account and even a private account.
The result was the same..

Comment: This sounds slightly off topic. Have you tried it on another OS? Does it work there?

Comment: Turned out to be related to my modem.. works fine now.